# how to restrict Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * when deploying application using tomcat and nginx in AWS

Tags: nginx, tomcat, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

We are deploying application in AWS using nginx and tomcat. It is Grails 3 application. We want to restrict the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to only domain that we allow rather than `*`.

We have added some change in nginx conf file but it is adding additional header as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://*.xyz` and keep `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. So basically sending two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. The application is behind application load balancer.

Comment: Add your nginx config (omitting the private parts) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that additional Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is coming from siteminder server rather than nginx or ALB.